# Can a photodiode emit light?

Tags: diodes, photodiode

I read that an LED (primarily emits light) can also be used as a photodiode (primarily detects light). Is this true in reverse? I mean, can a photodiode also emit light?

Comment: Give it enough power and yes, it will (briefly) emit light... and smoke... and noise ;)

Answer (score 6):

Yes it can, and does.  Any recombination of the carriers (electron and holes) which happens all the time will emit light with an energy level corresponding to the bandgap, 1.12 eV (minus just a little bit) ~ 1 um for Silicon.  Although, it must be noted that this is a very inefficient process.  It is not used directly because of that but is used in some diagnostic tools.

Comment: Do I only need to connect it in reverse?

Comment: Oops, a typical PIN silicon photodiode will not emit light.  It's an indirect band gap material.  Now a GaAs photodiode may... I've never used one and don't know for sure.

Comment: @GeorgeHerold That is flat out wrong, it _IS_ a very inefficient process, it needs to involve k-space (phonons) to emit but it will emit nevertheless. Surface effects, traps and defects all will emphasize the process.  If you were right then some very key diagnostic equipment wouldn't work.

Comment: @Kozuch the recombination rate will increase if forward biased.  Keep in mind that since the emission is essentially at energy of the bandgap, you can't use Si to detect this.  Probably InGaAs would be your best choice.

Comment: @placeholder, OK my bad, it will not emit very much light. I played with this a bit. http://www.pvlighthouse.com.au/calculators/recombination%20calculator/recombination%20calculator.aspx  For intrinsic Si the rate is darn small!  (Oh what diagnostic equipment are you referring to?)

Comment: This answer would be better if you added that this emission is vastly less efficient than what goes on in a LED.

Comment: @placeholder, I pulled Pankove ("optical processes in Semi's") off the shelf.  He lists the intrinsic radiative recombination time for some semi's.  Si is 4.6 hours... typical numbers are in the microsecond range.  GaAs is not listed.

Comment: @ThePhoton fair enough!

Comment: @GeorgeHerold I have that book as well, however, I don't have the book with me right now, but I'd say that result is likely for Intrinsic Si (i.e material that gets doped if you look at it wrong), with no electric fields imposed and no drift. Does it have the information for typical doping levels? even very light doping say 1 e-16? I was referring to PEM _ Photon Emission Microscopy, which in all fairness really lights up with defects.  But you can see light emitted from Recombination events in junctions.

Comment: Yeah Pankove's got numbers for 10^17/cm^3.  it's 2.5 ms.  The rate should go as the carrier density(?), (once it's well away from intrinsic doping.)  Intrinsic concentration (at 300k) is ~10^10 (?)  4.6 hours/2.5ms is 6x10^6, not a bad guesstimate.  Really sharp pn junctions might give more light.. but spread out PIN photodiodes....

Answer (score 1):

A direct bandgap photodiode can certainly emit light, and the amount of light can be modulated by loading it differently.

Shine light above the bandgap energy on a III-V junction and you will make carriers. If you have left the leads unconnected rather than reverse-biased it, then those carriers may spend enough time near each other so that a significant fraction will recombine with each other, rather than at non-radiative sites such as defects and dopants.

In effect, photodiodes will "fluoresce" at the bandgap energy. Short it or reverse bias it, and you can collect more of those e-h pairs and the glow (during illumination) will be reduced.

It doesn't really matter if you create e-h pairs electrically or photonically, once they are there, a fraction will undergo radiative recombination.

See for example the answer(s) to [Do III-V based photovoltaics “glow” (photo-luminesce) when illuminated but not loaded?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/270125/83380)